# Dummit & Foote, $\langle g\rangle \leq C_G(g)$ for any $g \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

Let $G$ be a group and $C_G(g)$ denote the conjugacy class of $g$. In chapter 4.3 of Dummit and Foote, it is noted often that $\langle g\rangle \leq C_G(g)$ and this fact is used throughout some of the exercises (as a tool/hint) in the text.

The following is an example (chapter 4.3 page 124)

> [image]

But $C_{Q_8}(i) = \{\pm i \}$, it is not possible to reach $\pm 1$ in the conjugation $gig^{-1}$.

> [image]

In this example $C_G(\cdot)$ is the centralizer (page 59 chapter 2.3)

Can someone clarify the first example for me?

Comment: Does the author actually state that $C_G()$ is the conjugacy class? Because: (1) it is unlikely for authors to change essential notation throughout a textbook; (2) $(g)\subseteq C_G(g)$ suggests centralizer.

Comment: $C_G(g)$ does not usually denote the conjugacy class of $g$, it denotes the centralizer of $g$ in $G$. The reason the centralizer is important when looking at the conjugacy class is that the map from $G$ to the conjugacy class of $g$ given by mapping $x$ to $xgx^{-1}$ factors through $G/C_{G}(g)$.

Comment: The preceding class equaton: https://imgur.com/a/N71GCW8. They used this notation.

Comment: @hawk As I suspected, the author indeed said centralizer.

Comment: You are misinterpreting that equation. $C_G(g)$ *still* denotes the centralizer of $g$; the point is that the order of the conjugacy class of $g$ is the **index** of the centralizer of $g$ in $G$.

Comment: Ah okay i misread it. It looks like a preceding proposition they did use centralizer. Thanks.

Comment: Some books use $C_g$ for the conjugacy class; perhaps taht is the source of your confusion? (P.S. Generally, it is a bad idea to post images in lieu of text; the site cannot search the images for text, and they can cause problems with interfaces, in addition to messing up accessibility tools that readers may be using).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply mistaken; $C_G(g)$ is denoting the centralizer of $g$ in $G$ throughout:
$$C_G(g) = \{x\in G\mid xg=gx\}.$$

The reason this subgroup shows up in the consideration of conjugacy classes is that there is a bijection between the cosets of $C_G(g)$ in $G$ and the conjugates of $g$ in $G$.

Indeed, if $xC_G(g) = yC_G(g)$, then there exists $h\in C_G(g)$ such that $x=yh$. Then 
$$\begin{align}xgx^{-1} & =(yh)g(yh)^{-1}\\ 
&= yhgh^{-1}y^{-1}\\ 
& = yghh^{-1}y^{-1} &\text{(since }hg=gh\text{)}\\ 
&= ygy^{-1}. 
\end{align}$$
And if $zgz^{-1}=wgw^{-1}$, then $w^{-1}zg = gw^{-1}z$, hence $w^{-1}z\in C_G(g)$, so $zC_G(g) = wC_G(g)$.

Thus, the size of the conjugacy class of $g$ is the index of $C_G(g)$ in $G$.

If we let $C_g = \{xgx^{-1}\mid x\in G\}$ be the conjugacy class of $g$, this amounts to
$$|C_g| = [G:C_G(g)]$$
which is a special case of the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.

And of course, every power of $g$ commutes with $g$, so $\langle g\rangle \subseteq C_G(g)$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: In the first example, they claim $[Q_8 : (i) ] = 2$ and hence $C_G(i) = (i)$. Is there specific reasoning? I can only reason it out by brute force but I don't think this is what they are suggesting. I think they re suggest a pattern for $(g) \leq C_G(g) \leq G$ and if $[G: (g)] = p$, then $(g) = C_G(g)$

Comment: @Hawk: Since the centralizer of $I$ contains $\langle i\rangle$ and is a subgroup of $Q_8$, if the index of $\langle i\rangle$ is $2$, then the centralizer is either $\langle i\rangle$ or all of $Q_8$. But the only way the centralizer can be all of $Q_8$ is if the element $i$ is in the center of $Q_8$ (commutes with everything), *which is not the case*. So the centralizer of $i$ must be just $\langle i\rangle$.

Comment: What you write at the end is *almost* true: if $p$ is a prime, and $[G:\langle g\rangle]=p$, then either $C_G(g)=\langle g\rangle$ (if $g$ is not central), or $C_G(g)=G$ (if $g$ is central). Because there can be no subgroup strictly between $\langle g\rangle$ and $G$ in that case.

Comment: Is there something special about being index $2$ that implies the centralizer is either (i or all of $G$?

Comment: It’s the fact that if $K\leq H\leq G$ are subgroups, then $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$. So if the left hand side is prime (for instance, $2$), then one of the factors on the right hand side must equal $1$. You should already know this if you are reading about conjugacy classes....

Comment: Ah okay the index equation. I am guessing this is used for the "generalization".

Answer (score 1):

Given a group $G$ and a subset $S\subseteq G$, then the centralizer $C_G(S)$ is the set of elements of $G$ that fix each element of $S$ under conjugation.  Equivalently, these are the elements of $G$ that commute with each of the elements of $S$.

So, for instance, if $G=Q_8$ and $S=\{i\}$, then you can check that the elements of $G$ that commute with $i$ are exactly $\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$.

On the other hand, the conjugacy class of $i$---the set of elements which are conjugate to $i$---is exactly $\{\pm i\}$.  It appears that you have confused $C_G(x)$ for the conjugacy class of $x$.